# Relative paths or absolute?

Tags: http, server, path, relative-path, absolute-path

Is there any difference for server when I use relative paths or absolute ones on my website?

For example I include 50 .js files this way:

```
<script src="relative/path/to/file.js"></script>
```

Or using absolute path like this:

```
<script src="http://example.com/path/to/file.js"></script>
```

Is there any difference **for server** when I use absolute paths? Are there any more request/loads/operations that server must cope with or the type of path doesn't make any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't affect server performance.

With a relative path, your browser takes the URL and adds it to the URL path already in the address bar.

For example, if a page requested is: `http://example.com/folder1/index.php` and it has a link pointing to `folder2/index.php` and its clicked, then the page `http://example.com/folder1/folder2/index.php` will then be requested from the server. The web browser does the conversion for you.